# Samsung Washer WF218ANS-XAC troubleshooting help needed, smoke in the drum compartment

Tags: washing-machine, washer

I think that our washer is toasted and I would like to know if it can be fixed before I decide to buy another one

Here is the history of this issue:

**Yesterday** my wife was doing the laundry and the washer in the basement started making a huge noise , I  was under the impression that the house was coming apart :-) . We both run to the basement, it was the washer that was making noise...it stopped by the time we got there. It was the final minute of the program as the timer was showing (I guess it was high speed squeezing) 
We thought something was misplaced in the drum and that made the noise

**Today** my wife used the washer again and she is telling me that the washer worked for 30 minutes but it was making more than usual noise so she let it work ..at the end when she went back to see what was going on there was water on the floor and it was dripping from the bottom side of the drum window on the floor. The program ended and she tried to get the clothes out of the washer...that was when she noticed smoke coming out for the drum compartment and she called me.

My first move to troubleshoot this was to see if the drum is moving freely and by giving it a quick spin I noticed that the drum is facing some friction. By the sound it is like it is tangent to a rubber piece or something.

I am handy and I can probably take the job to fix it if it is doable. I just wanted to hear from those of you who have experience with this your opinion what could this be and what would be the steps to take to troubleshoot it

Also if you are aware of any place where I can download a service manual it would be greatly appreciated

**Update:** I have removed the back cover to look at the rotor and springs and I found this part sitting there:
[image]

OK I now know what happened. Or at least I guess what happened. The spider shaft assemble cracked and a piece of it was projected into the plastic case of the drum that was perforated ....this is by far a case of poor quality and manufactured defect. Below is a picture of the damaged piece and the damaged case. It is just horrible. I will post another question to find out if it iw worth ordering a new assembly.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Was your washer subject to the Samsung washer recall?

Comment: I had no idea there was a recall... I bought it with the house 4 years ago

Comment: I've actually had a specific type of issue like this with one of my washing machine. It began to smoke and I thought the drum was burning. Contacting an appliance repairer actually saved me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your front loader drum unit will have a slightly different shaft and bearing system than my top loader drum washer. But I have had the bearings go out twice in 12 years in my unit. When the bearings go bad the high speed spin cycle sounds like a freight train is going through our house.

I had to purchase a couple of special tools but replacing the bearings was a fairly straightforward task albeit with many steps. So you may want to debug to see if it is the bearings in your washer that have gone bad.

Note I put your washer model number in to Google and got quite a few hits for manuals and parts lists.

Comment: how about the smoke? did you have it too?

Comment: I did not have the smoke. It is possible that in your case the bearings got so bad that they nearly froze up and made the direct drive motor severely overheat due to the overload. In the worst case the motor windings may have burned and you may be faced with replacing that as well. That would be quite a few more $$$ than just having to replace bearings.

Comment: any idea how to check that?

Comment: It would be tough to suggest how to check what may have burned in your washer. Often a visual check and a smell test can lead to some primary clues. More detailed analysis of the motor or possibly the motor driver electronics board is kind of out of scope here.

Comment: I think this video takes me through how to take it apart and look at it 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIB2nN7CcOQ

Answer (score 0):

Hi for anyone who wonder what make the smoke in the drum my suggestion is to check the front rubber boot around the drum. Mine was completely melt\cut by the stainless steel drum.We also found grey rubber pellet inside the drum. So our guess is that the drum got so out of balance at high speed that it make a lot of friction on the rubber and melt it.Hope this help.