# Samsung Washer WF218ANS-XAC -is it worth repairing?

Tags: washer

This question branched from this one [Samsung Washer WF218ANS-XAC troubleshooting help needed, smoke in the drum compartment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/154843/samsung-washer-wf218ans-xac-troubleshooting-help-needed-smoke-in-the-drum-compa)

The long story is in the thread pointed above. Short story..it broke and smoke came out of the drum when my wife opened the front door.

I could order the spider shaft assembly but I don;t know how to determine if other parts are broken. The motor could be fried as well. When I took it apart I could not see anything on the solenoids of the electrical motor ...

Edit: How can I tell if the bearing are all right  and it is centered and balanced like before?

[image]
[image]

Comment: One has to question the sheer amount of corrosion on that part. It is possible that this part broke after being weakened from the corrosion. Before making a repair decision I would think you would want to understand this issue and what caused it.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based and shoud be closed. You've identified at least 2 things wrong which I beleive if the parts are still available they are about 180$+ (might be closer to $300)..... And you've identified concern over another expensive part. Is the time/money to sink into the machine vs. buying a new one worth it? Is there anything newer models have that appeal to you? Given what has failed here, do you want to make this repair and get a few more years? will it? Has it lived its usefulness? cost/years/months = $month. Hopefully this helps you weigh it.

Comment: Well I was expecting replies more on the line of this or that will not work because this and that. Profitability is of course important but it come into second place if technical reasons would prevent the repair. I am looking for those reasons not to do it firstly!

Comment: The old Whirlpool/Kenmore/etc. top loaders (I have one) basically lasted a long time except for a few relatively easy & inexpensive parts that fail every 'x' years (and are easier than ever to fix thanks to Amazon parts and YouTube instructional videos). The newer machines are more efficient (water & energy), more powerful, more features (connectivity, varied cycles, etc.) but MUCH more expensive to repair due to more unique & proprietary parts and more complex mechanisms.